# List comprehension with multiple conditions and value reassignment

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I have a function that has several conditions (5 exactly) that model this statement:

```
for n, i in enumerate(EPS_List_EPSV):
        if i == 'Very Satisfied':
            EPS_List_EPSV[n] = 1
        elif i == 'Satisfied':
            EPS_List_EPSV[n] = 2
        elif i == 'Dissatisfied':
            EPS_List_EPSV[n] = 3
        else:
            EPS_List_EPSV[n] = 4
```

I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way of writing this, due to the function's length being absurdly long. I understand list comprehension in dealing with one variable but is there a way to write this using list comprehension? Writing it correctly is evading me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dictionary and a list comprehension:

```
corr = {"Very Satisfied":1, "Satisfied":2, "Dissatisfied":3}
EPS_List_EPSV = [corr.get(el, 4) for el in EPS_List_EPSV]
```

For example:

```
EPS_List_EPSV = ["Very Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Other"]
```

with the use of the above code becomes: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: we have `dict.get` method for this kind of things

Comment: `corr[el] if el in corr.keys() else 4` is `corr.get(el, 4)`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense to use it in fact. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict`:

```
d = {
    'Very Satisfied': 1,
    'Satisfied': 2,
    'Dissatisfied': 3    
}

EPS_List_EPSV = ['Very Satisfied', 'Something Else', 'Satisfied', 'Something Else', 'Dissatisfied'

for n, i in enumerate(EPS_List_EPSV):
    EPS_List_EPSV[n] = d.get(i, 4)

print(EPS_List_EPSV)
[1, 4, 2, 4, 3]
```

`d.get` is to return `4` if any undefined key is given.

Answer (score 0):

If I were I would create a dict

```
dictio = {'Very Satisfied' : 1, 'Satisfied': 2, 'Dissatisfied' : 3, 'other' : 4}
```

Then your code shoud look like :

```
for n, i in enumerate(EPS_List_EPSV):
    EPS_List_EPSV = dictio[i]
```

Edit : Chris answer is more accurate since it does not raise KeyError in case the ESP_List_EPSV contains a word that is not in the dict